# How to get syntax highlighting of Vue components like <vue-component />?

Tags: vue.js, syntax-highlighting

Currently I am using prettier and Vetur but neither one will highlight components unless I code them as  which is not the practice of the company I am working for. Anyone have any idea how to get syntax highlighting on vue components when they are written ?